# WordPress website loads fine on desktop browsers but Safari for iOS cannot load it completely

Tags: mobile

Everything is fine on desktop browsers but Safari for iOS' loading bar for my website shies from reaching 50% for a really long time. The problem persists across multiple iOS devices I have. I have not tested on Android because I have sent it for repair and it's going to take a while to be back. I use a Content Delivery Network for my website but it's caching cannot be the reason because I already tried disabling it to no avail. I also use W3 Total Cache and I moved all of the JavaScript before the closing `</body>` tag. I thought that it could be the reason for the problem but the website loads fine on Desktop using the same connection for the iOS devices.

Comment: Just because it loads ok on desktop and not on mobile using the same connection, doesn't mean the problem is not related to your caching. To rule it out, disabled all caching, CDN, W3 Total Cache completely. Flush caches, browser and iOS devices. Also if you were logged in on desktop you may have been viewing uncached version of the site. So we need to rule out all possibilities.

Comment: I had already done every single thing you mentioned. I had deleted safari website data on the ios devices as well

Comment: I tested on Opera, Firefox, Chrome on desktop too.

Comment: Are you positively sure you are being served non-cached pages on iOS? Have you got debugging enabled? What did you do to verify the page was not cached...

Comment: I purged all the caches using W3 Total Cache and disabled the CDN delivery.

Comment: Disable your current theme, all plugins. Then re-enable one of the default WordPress themes. Check if the problem persists. If not, then re-enable your original theme, test... if no problem, re-enable 1 plugin at a time, test, rinse repeat until you find the likely offender.

Comment: @userabuser ok.

Comment: @userabuser I wrote an answer you should check out. and you shouldn't have such a name. you are good and not an abuser. Maybe you should mark my answer as the right one as well because it is. Thanks for being super cooperative.

Comment: :D ... glad you have it sorted. I cannot mark your answer; only you can. So please do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was because of a plugin called Easy Social Sharing Buttons version 3.5 I bought from Code Canyon. It is quite feature rich and may slow down your website. I would not say you should avoid it but I would advise you to do an extensive research that your website is running fine on different devices and connections if you are going to use it and similar plugins. ESSB's stylesheet was 5 times the size of my whole website's stylesheet and it has many JS files as well. Use Pingdom Tools to find out what is causing your website to be slow just like I did and found out.